# BeautifulSoup findAll() returns class contents twice

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I run the code below, I noticed that it returns the contents of the class twice. Is this something to do with it picking up the mobile site as well?

Also, is there a way to get only the text without having to relist the classes individually like I have here?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

book_list = []

page = requests.get('https://www.penguin.co.uk/articles/2018/100-must-read-classic-books.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

test = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'text'})

for i in test:
    book_list.append(i.text)

print(book_list[0])
print(book_list[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that each item is wrapped inside two `<div>` with class `text`:

```
<div class="text">
<div class="cmp-text text">
```

so you are selecting with findAll these two elements for each item. The simplest solution is to filter out the redundant divs, that contain divs with class text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

book_list = []

page = requests.get('https://www.penguin.co.uk/articles/2018/100-must-read-classic-books.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

test = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'text'})

for i in test:
    if not i.find('div', {'class': 'text'}): # <-- here we check, if div doesn't contain another div with class  text
        book_list.append(i.text)

for b in book_list:
    print(b)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
They broke boundaries and challenged conceptions. We asked our readers for their must-reads; from timeless non-fiction to iconic bestsellers, these are their essential recommends. 
Books ranked in no particular order. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1. Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen
We said: It is a truth universally acknowledged that when most people think of Jane Austen they think of this charming and humorous story of love, difficult families and the tricky task of finding a handsome husband with a good fortune.
They said: Philosophy, history, wit, and the most passionate love story.
Francesca, Twitter

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2. To Kill a Mockingbird by Harper Lee 
We said: A novel before its time, Harper Lee’s Pulitzer-prize winner addresses issues of race, inequality and segregation with both levity and compassion. Told through the eyes of loveable rogues Scout and Jem, it also created one of literature’s most beloved heroes – Atticus Finch, a man determined to right the racial wrongs of the Deep South.
They said: A jarring & poignantly beautiful story about how humans treat each other.
Greygardens, Twitter

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

use css selector `:not(.cmp-text)`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

book_list = []

page = requests.get('https://www.penguin.co.uk/articles/2018/100-must-read-classic-books.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

test = soup.select("div.text:not(.cmp-text)")

for i in test:
    book_list.append(i.text)
```